# Java: Calculating Employee's Wage

Tags: java

I have again a problem regarding on how to display the calculated wage of the employee..
When I type in the hourly rate, the Gross Salary won't display..

Here's what I've done so far..

The WageCalcu.java

```
  public class WageCalcu
  {
      private String employeeName;
      private int hours;
      private double rate, pay;

      public void setEmployeeName ( String name )
      {
          employeeName = name;
      }
      public String getEmployeeName()
      {
          return employeeName;
      }
      public double calculatePay( int hours, double rate )
      {
          if ( hours > 40 )
          { 
              int extraHours = hours - 40;
              pay = ( 40 * rate ) + ( extraHours * rate );
          }
          else pay = hours * rate;

          return pay;
      }
      public void displayEmployee()
      {
          System.out.printf( "Employee's name: %s", getEmployeeName() );
          System.out.printf( "\nGross Salary: ", + pay );
      }
  }
```

The Employee.java

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
  public class Employee 
  {    
      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
          Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in);
          WageCalcu employee = new WageCalcu();

          System.out.print( "Enter Employee %s name: " );
          String name = input.nextLine();
          employee.setEmployeeName( name );

          System.out.print( "Enter how many hours worked: " );
          int hours = input.nextInt();

          System.out.print( "Enter hourly rate: " );
          double rate = input.nextInt();

          employee.calculatePay( hours, rate );
          employee.displayEmployee();

          System.out.println();

      }
  }
```

Comment: Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.   This helps the reader.  You would not want to make it **harder** for us to help, would you?

Comment: For wage calculations, you should **really** be using BigDecimal instead of double.

Answer (score 7):

I'm sure you meant:

> System.out.printf( "\nGross Salary: %f", pay);

One more thing

```
double rate = input.nextInt();
```

Should be

```
double rate = input.nextDouble();
```

If you're really expecting a real number.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed %s in `printf( "\nGross Salary: ", + pay );`

Answer (score 0):

I would put: `System.out.printf( "\nGross Salary: %.2f", pay);`  to show 2 decimals.

Answer (score 0):

Five years late to this party, but I'll speak my piece.

You've set it up to determine how many overtime hours an employee has, but you're not calculating their overtime pay.

What you have:

```
pay = ( 40 * rate ) + ( extraHours * rate );
```

What it should be:

```
pay = ( 40 * rate ) + ( extraHours * rate * 1.5);
```